# Why all the pins on a chip are not GPIOs?

Tags: linux, gpio

Documentation of GPIOs in Linux states:

> A "General Purpose Input/Output" (GPIO) is a flexible software-controlled
>   digital signal.  They are provided from many kinds of chip, and are familiar
>   to Linux developers working with embedded and custom hardware.

If we are capable of control the behavior of a pin, then why all the pins on a chip are not GPIOs?

OR

How can we provide functionality through software for a pin on chip?

Please explain.

Comment: *"why all the pins on a chip are not GPIOs?"* -- Then how to supply power and provide ground?  What about clock signals?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may belong to https://electronics.stackexchange.com site of the Network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you design an integrated circuit (chip) you design with some component model in mind, those internal components may have specific needs that can not be reassigned among different pins, then those pins are fixed function.

For example pins related to memory controller have a very strict performance requirements set (in terms of signal integrity, toggle rate, output driver, capacitance), those pins are fixed function not reassignable, thus you can not use those pins for GPIO. If you do it you will end with a slower chip because the additional circuit change those values becoming unfeasible. Other example are power domain pins (those tipically called VCC, VDD, VEE, GND,).

Thats why GPIO pins are always shared with slow interfaces like SPI, I2C, SMBUS but never with fast interfaces like SATA, DDR, etc.

In other cases the only reason is because the chip doesnt make sense without a particular component, for example, given you must to have RAM memory, then RAM dedicated pins doesnt need to be reassignable because you never will implement the system without RAM memory and never will need reuse those pins for GPIO

Comment: Thank you very much bro!

Answer (score 1):

All the pins in SOC are not GPIO. A specific group of pins mapped as GPIO. Other pins are configured for specific interfaces like DDR, SPI, I2C... etc, which includes clock, data and power supply pins. GPIO is generic pins can be used for any purpose based on user requirement. It can be used for handling IRQs, trigger Resets, Glow LEDs..etc.

for example, Consider a FPGA is connected to SOC via GPIOs. User need to program the FPGA via these GPIO pins. In SOC side user need to write a specific program with mentioned sequence to drive those GPIO to program the FPGA config file.

Comment: If IRQs, trigger Resets, Glow LEDs..etc are handled through GPIOs, it means that these are "programmed". Then, why can't we do the same programming the protocols mentioned - DDR, SPI, I2C... etc using GPIOs?

Comment: To handle IRQs, Finally end device will trigger some state (either low to high or high to low) to SOC via GPIO pin. In Kernel we need to monitor the pin the handle the Interrupts.

Comment: If we use GPIO to program DDR, we need to follow the protocol. Its quite difficult (timing and speed) to handle in Software. So SOC vendors use those protocol in their hardware logic (firmware running in SOC), to reduce the complication in software.

Comment: we can do for some low speed protocols. Like i mentioned above, we can program a simple FPGA using GPIOs.  Xilinx follows a simple protocol to program their FPGAs. check this link 
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp502.pdf

Comment: Thank you bro! Can you please provide me some links to proceed further study? :)

Comment: For xilinx programming, open source is available in 'c'.  https://github.com/RobertCNelson/u-boot/blob/master/drivers/fpga/spartan3.c

Comment: You can use the above document and respective source for detailed understanding.

Comment: Kudos bro! You're very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: *"Other pins are configured for specific protocols like DDR, SPI, I2C... etc."* -- "Interface" is a more appropriate word than "protocol".

Comment: Yes.. Interface is appropriate word, which includes clock and power signals.